# Replace cells in an Excel sheets with a different value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that has around 900 rows of data and I need to run through one of the columns and replace what that column has with a different value depending on what is currently in the column.

For example, say column F has these values entered:
Adj/Aviation & Transportation 
Adj/Aviation & Transportation 
Adj/Aviation & Transportation 
Adj ESL Instructor 
Adj/ESL 
Adj/Aviation & Transportation 
Professor/Aviation 
Professor-Aviation 
Associate Chair, Professor 
Professor 
Prof/Aviation & Transportation 
Adjunct Professor 
Professor 
Professor 
Adj/Aviation 
Professor 
Dir Master's Prog/Assoc Prof 
Chair/Assoc Prof/Aviation&TS 
Adj Asst Prof/Aviation 
Assistant Professor/Aviation 
Adj.Asst. Prof-Aviation

I want to run through this column and if one of the cells contains the value "Aviation" I want to clear the content in that cell and enter "Aviation & Transportation" instead.

If anyone can show me how to accomplish this task that would mean the world!

Comment: What have you done ? If you have no knowledge of VBA then your question is useless to the community because we will just write code for you. If you already know VBA, then try something and come back with what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: And that is assuming that the task is too big to simply use Find..Replace.

Comment: Oh and one last comment. If you don't mind using another column you can just write a chart of the replacements you want to do and use VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have a better solution. You can use wildcards in the Find..Replace menu.

Hit Ctrl F > Replace > Enter `*Aviation*` then write whatever you want to replace the cell value to. I tested it and it works. You can enable or disable case sensitivity.

Comment: The wild card helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column and populate it with a formula something like:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Aviation",B1))),"Aviation & Transportation",B1)
```

- This is untested, might need some syntax adjustment as I haven't put it in excel. But it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can then just hide the original column... or copy then paste(values) to replace the formula with the new data. Then the extra column can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Sub replace()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(Rws, 6))

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If c Like "*Aviation*" Then c = "Aviation & Transportation"
    Next c
End Sub
```

You can also use the Autofilter in your VBA code.

Start 
[image]
result
[image]

Use the autofilter code.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*Aviation*"
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(Rws, 6)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.Value = "Aviation & Transportation"
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0

End Sub
```